# Pages doesn't appear in search (NAV 2018 extension)

Tags: search, visual-studio-extensions, navision, dynamics-nav

I have a NAV 2018 extension with different pages. Those pages stopped appearing in search after I modified `app.json`.

In `app.json` I changed the name, description and version.

The `UsageCategory` property is set to `Documents` for all those pages.

Comment: Can you post details so somebody can reproduce it?

Comment: Hi Laurenz, I found out that this happens because UsageCategory can't be used on some pages. It sounds very strange and I still investigating why those pages doesn't like UsageCategory property.

For instance I have 2 pages which are almost identical in structure. Its just the SourceTableView property that are different. But on 1 of them I can use UsageCategory and the other not.

Comment: Page 1: UsageCategory = Documents; 
    CaptionML =   ENU='xxxxxxxxx',    
    PageType = List;
    SourceTable = "xxxxxxx";
    SourceTableView = WHERE("Order No."=CONST(''));

Comment: Page 2:  
CaptionML = ENU='xxxxx',                
SourceTable = "xxxxxxxx";
SourceTableView = WHERE(HasEMSMSrvItemLine=CONST(false),
                            "Order No."=FILTER(<>''));
UsageCategory = Documents;

This page can take UsageCategory without any problem, but on Page 1, I get error. 
Following happens on page 1:
1. The RTC will not get started before the nav service is restarted.
2. No pages from my extension will appear in search.

Comment: I found out that if I set UsageCategory property on 15+ pages/reports I get the error "The server "DynamicsNAV90" was unable to process the request. The application will close.". But =<15 everything works fine.